# If in loop, nonetype

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writting some code in which I try to check every number in a range using a for loop and an if statement. The loop stops after the first check, and throws an error with message  *wrong type ,,None,, expected integer*, I'll give you what I have been asked to do:

Define a function findLine(prog, target) to perform the following. Assume prog is a list of strings containing a BASIC program, like the type generated by getBASIC(); assume target is a string containing a line number, which is the target of a GOTO statement. The function should return the index i (a number between 0 and len(prog)-1) such that prog[i] is the line whose label equals target. Hint 
Sample input/output: If you call
findLine(['10 GOTO 20','20 END'], '10')

```
def findLine(prog, target):
  L=[]
  for i in range(0, len(prog)):
     L=L+prog[i].split()
  for j in range(0,len(L)):
     i=L.index(L[j])
     if j == int(target):
       i=i//3
       return i
```

These is some information :

```
Running findLine(['10 GOTO 20', '20 END'], '20')… Error: findLine(['10 GOTO 20', '20 END'], '20') has wrong type "None" Type, expected Integer
```

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback? It looks like some stuff is missing here

Comment: `i = L.index(L[j])` ??? why not just `i = j`? -- I suppose it could matter if you want the *first* instance of `L[j]`, but this still seems weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop isn't stopping after the first check: instead, it's never successfully returning. This function returns based on the following loop:

```
for j in range(0,len(L)):
    i=L.index(L[j])
    if j == int(target):
        i=i//3
        return i
```

But if the condition `j == int(target)` is never satisfied, the loop will finish, and the function `findLine` will return `None`.

ETA: Now that you've explained what the task is: your construction of the `L` list isn't the right way to go about the problem:

```
  for i in range(0, len(prog)):
     L=L+prog[i].split()
```

This will produce `['10', 'GOTO', '20', '20', 'END']`. In this case, you don't know which line is which! Still, splitting it is the right direction. What if you just add the label from each split line:

```
  for i in range(0, len(prog)):
     L.append(prog[i].split()[0])
```

That will produce an `L` equal to `['10', '20']`, which is much closer to what you're looking for. The last step would be to get the index of the target in that array (which you already know how to do!)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's None is because your code is falling off the end of the function.  The `if j == int(target)` block never runs.

Your code doesn't really make sense.  In your loop, `j` will take on values from 0 up to however many lines there are the BASIC code you pass to the function.  So in your example `j` will equal 0, then 1.  It will never equal 20, which is your target line.  It seems you want to do `if L[j][0] == target`.

In addition to that, you are iterating over the lists in an unpythonic way by using the length of the list.  You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to learn how to use for loops Pythonically.

Answer (score 1):

```
def findLine(prog, target):
  for i in range(0, len(prog)):
      if prog[i].startswith(target):
          return i
```

This should be an answer to your problem statement.

Comment: Yes these works, but I just wanted something to help me to debug my code, I'm sorry for not tagging my question ,,homework,, . Smart solution, anyway.